# Ruby logger scope

Tags: ruby, function, variables, logging, scope

I am trying to create a simple logging solution for my program using ruby's built in logger function. At the moment, what I have is the initialization for the logger like this:

```
class Setup

  def initialize
    logger = Logger.new(logfile.log)
    logger.level = 'DEBUG'
    logger.datetime_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

And then when I try to call to the logger within other functions in the same class with:

```
logger.info('testlog')
```

I get an error saying:

```
undefined local variable or method 'logger'
```

How should I access the logger from outside the local scope of the method it is defined in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logger` is a local variable, which is only visible in the area where it was defined.  Rename it to `@logger` to make it be an instance variable which is stored inside the object and can be used from any of the object's methods.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. When I tried this, I get an error saying "Comparison of fixnum with string failed", referring to a file in the ruby files. Any ideas for this?

Comment: Helping you debug the rest of your program (which you haven't even posted) is outside of the scope of the question you originally asked.  Since I already answered this question, you should click the checkmark to accept the answer and then post a new question with your full code and error message.